# Флаги в C#

Tags: c#

Как организовать функции сохранить и сохранить как (в текстовом редакторе) при помощи флагов, которые проверяют сохранен ли был файл? Тобишь, если не был сохранен, то сохранить как (через диалоговое окно), если был сохранен, то файл молча перезаписывется. Я о флагах ничего совсем не знаю, в нэте толком ничего не нашел. Как все это выглядит?

Comment: если ответ вас устраивает, лайкните (палец вверх) или примите его (галочка), или и то и другое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужная какая-то переменная, в которой будет храниться текущее состояние файла.
Например **bool flag_saved** Если файл только создан, то заносите в переменную false, а при сохранении проверяете значение этой переменной - если false, то сохраняете как, если true, то перезаписываете. И тд...

В какую область видимости засунуть переменную - зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения. Это может быть глобальная переменная приложения (может быть даже static), или если у вас файл в программе организован в виде отдельного класса, то этот флаг можно сделать прямо в нем.